# css will not load, Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php

Tags: html, hyperlink, http-headers

I have tried everything and cannot figure this out, I am not terribly knowledgable about servers and setting them up, the company that this site is on decided to run their website off of GoDaddy servers which leads me to believe that might be at the root of this problem but I will try to explain this as best as I can.

I have a simple HTML page, with some css...when the css is inclusive on the page itself it works fine.

IE

```
<html>
<head>
     <style>
#topbanner {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
height: 40px;
width:100%;
background-color:#000;
opacity: .5;
}
#map {
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(img/jeanmap.png);
height:679px;
width: 1024px;
position: relative;
}
      </style>
</head>
<body>
   etc... etc...
```

however when I link the same css styles via a stylesheet, I get nothing on my page, literally nothing.

IE

```
    <html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   etc... etc...
```

When testing in Firefox I get no errors, and I can see all the styles in the .css file and I can download it, in Chrome I dont see my styles but can download it, and in Chrome I get the following error, `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php`

I also link to a few javascript scripts as well and those give the same error but do load, but obviously nothing works because my css is empty.

What exactly is the issue here, I have never had this happen before and am so lost.

I dont believe its a server issue as in the root folder I do the same thing and it works fine, this is just in a folder and it still isnt working there

to clarify this is my file structure

```
root/

    index.php
    css/
    img/
    js/
    problematic folder/
                  index.php
                  css/
                     style.css
                  img/
                  js/
```

the reasoning for having another css folder and another img folder and another js folder is because this is a secondary project that eventually will end up on its own server but for now for testing and working out the design it is nested on my server.

I have a my .htaccess in my root folder with the following...

```
# add various mime types
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/ogg .oga
AddType audio/webm .webma
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogg
```

and also tried adding an htaccess file in the problematic directory but that didnt help either

Comment: This is a problem for me again with a client who is stuck in godaddy, I have moved my server to solve the problem but I dont have this option with this client

Comment: Seems that the css file is served by a php script and not the Apache itself. If you are using rewrite rules check they do not pass the css file request to your php script.

Comment: Taking a look to your whole .htaccess and your Apache configuration files could help a lot to find the problem. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the rewriting rules or in your php script handling of requests for "static" files (not setting the right content type there, not an Apache question). At least a link to the site to carefully read the headers could be somehow useful...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a server configuration problem. If you are using Apache look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Comment: This is the part that I dont know too much about, but I already have this in my .htaccess file, but it is in my root folder, do I also need it in my problematic folder as well?? `# add various mime types
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
`

Comment: Adding a .htaccess file to my problematic folder did not do anything...this may be more than an .htaccess problem however I am really limited in what I can do server side thanks to GoDaddy